# Why is python listening on port 8000?

Tags: python, sockets

Dears, 
I wanted to ask if anybody has details on why python is listening to port 8000 (local and remote connections as well).
Can it be a backdoor ? I tried to telnet to the ip/port and the connection is accepted.
Thanks in advance!

I run `sudo lsof -i tcp:8000`, and it yelded:

```
COMMAND PID USER FD TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME 
ajenti-pa 3598 root 8u IPv4 10912 0t0 TCP li499-163.members.linode.com:8000 (LISTEN)
```

I see Ajenti (some kind of admin panel) listening. I will try to find out more. Thank you.

Comment: `pgrep python` and look for any servers.

Comment: Try visiting `localhost:8000` in a web browser

Comment: Visited on browser, but no response. If i telnet it connects...

Answer (score 2):

Find out which program has the port open with

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:8000
```

Foe example, since I know I'm running `sshd`, I'll check for port tcp:22 here:

```
$ sudo lsof -i tcp:22
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    1617 root    3u  IPv4  14360      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    1617 root    4u  IPv6  14362      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
```

Of course, read `man lsof` BEFORE you execute the command. After all, I could be wrong or misleading.

Then, you can use `ps` to investigate the process with that PID, or inspect the `/proc/PID/` directory. The possibilities expand from here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Actually i used netstat -peanut
And i see python on that port. This is ehy im asking.

Comment: I run `sudo lsof -i tcp:8000`, and it yelded:

`COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ajenti-pa 3598 root    8u  IPv4  10912      0t0  TCP li499-163.members.linode.com:8000 (LISTEN)`

I see Ajenti (some kind of admin panel) listening. I will try to find out more.
Thank you.